# Secretary problem

Tags: game-theory, decision-theory

I have a problem with the secretary problem, I wanted to prove that maximum value of the probability function of choosing the best applicant is decreasing as n gets bigger. So, in other words:
$$F(n):=\max_{r\in [1,n]}\left(\frac{r-1}{n}\sum_{k=r}^{n}\frac{1}{k-1}\right)$$ is a decreasing function.

Comment: I think this is also known as the soulmate problem: https://www.inc.com/jessica-stillman/this-mathematician-claims-to-have-found-the-formula-for-finding-true-love.html

Comment: Yes, is a decreasing function for n>2 https://www.researchgate.net/publication/333102397_Odds-Theorem_and_Monotonicity